# How to set an image as background in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, imageicon

I can't figure out on how to fix the problem. Please help me. Thank you.

Here are the codes:

```
package com.gabriel.mvc.app;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.gabriel.mvc.shapeimpl.CarRenderer;
import com.gabriel.mvc.shapesfx.MyShape;
import com.gabriel.mvc.shapesfx.Renderer;

public class CarView extends JFrame {
    Image image;
    MyShape car;
    Renderer renderer = new CarRenderer();
    void init(MyShape car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
    void initUI() {     
        setVisible(true);
        image = new ImageIcon("2284910.jpg").getImage();
        setBounds(300,100,500,500);
        setSize(500,500);
    }
    
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        renderer.draw(g, car);
    }
}
```

**Here's the output, only solid color. Image not set as background. :(**
[image]

**Here's my expected output, I edited it on Photoshop.**
[image]

Comment: [Why shouldn't I call setVisible(true) before adding components?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10790457)

Comment: Hello @Tom! I did not understand, I'm a newbie. Please insert the solution in my code. Can you? :(

Comment: 1) Don't do custom painting in a `JFrame`. Instead do the painting in a `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method. 2) First thing, call the super method with the graphics instance passed. 3) Draw the image. 4) Draw the (any other elements on top of it, and / or add components or panels to that panel. - Done!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may refer on this code just replace your image source and add your CarRenderer  after the drawImage method of Graphics.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class SampleImageBg extends JFrame{ 
    private JDesktopPane panel;

    public SampleImageBg() {
        panel = new javax.swing.JDesktopPane() {
            private Image image;
            {
                try {
                    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("bg.jpeg"));// source of your background image
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
                g.clearRect(50,0,300,300); // add your renderer here instead
            }
        };

        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 600);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SampleImageBg();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @cyril-elijah, it worked! How to make the CarRenderer's background transparent?

Comment: Set the color before you draw any grahpics, just set the color and adjust the alpha on how you want to make it transparent.
`g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));`

Comment: (1-) @99c1af2caeecae31011a5dfeaa36a9, Don't use a JDesktopPane for the background. A JDesktopPane is designed to be used with JInternalFrames. For painting a background just use a `JPanel`. Also when doing custom painting you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method to give the panel a preferred size. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)